# Generalized counting elements in a slice based on multiple criteria in linear time

Tags: go

I need to count elements in many different ways in long arrays.

Here is an example of the use case for a special case:

```
func main() {
    test := []test{test{"A", "1", "$"}, test{"A", "2", "€"}, test{"B", "3", "$"}}

    countA := 0
    countDollar := 0
    countADollar := 0

    for _, e := range test {
        if e.prop1 == "A" {
            countA++
        }
        if e.prop3 == "$" {
            countDollar++
        }
        if e.prop1 == "A" && e.prop3 == "$" {
            countADollar++
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("countA: %v, count$: %v, countA$: %v\n", countA, countDollar, countADollar)
}
```

This will print

> countA: 2, count$: 2, countA$: 1

https://play.golang.org/p/R0nhwFpyN7H

The question is now: is there a way in go to generalize this so that I can count different sums based on attributes in one iteration over the array, without implementing each case separately?

---

Edit 2: here is a slightly better Version based on the suggestion by user Volker:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type test struct {
    prop1 string
    prop2 string
    prop3 string
}

func count2(data []test, f func(test) bool) {
        count1 := 0;
    for _, e := range data {
        if f(e) {
            count1++
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("count1: %v", count1)
}

func main() {
    data := []test{test{"A", "1", "$"}, test{"A", "2", "€"}, test{"B", "3", "$"}}
    
    myTestCrit := func(t test) bool {
        return t.prop1 == "A"
    }
    count2(data, myTestCrit)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/kB60gJCBkyn

---

**Edit 3**: here is a further generalization which accepts multiple counters. Thanks to Volker and Eli for their input. Perhaps the sources will be useful for others, too.

```
func count3(data []test, f []func(test) bool) {
        counts := make([]int, len(f));
    for _, e := range data {
        for i, fi := range f {
            if fi(e) {
                counts[i]++
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("counts: %v\n", counts)
}


func main() {
    data := []test{test{"A", "1", "$"}, test{"A", "2", "€"}, test{"B", "3", "$"}}
    
    myTestCrit := func(t test) bool {
        return t.prop1 == "A"
    }
    
    myTestCritDollar := func(t test) bool {
        return t.prop3 == "$"
    }
    
    
    countCrits := make([]func(t test) bool, 2)
    countCrits[0] = myTestCrit
    countCrits[1] = myTestCritDollar
    count3(data, countCrits)
}
```

---

Edit: I am also open to suggestions on how to improve the question. Its a legitimate issue I have and a general approach would very much simplify my code.

Comment: No, there is no language construct, but if you use a `func (test) bool` as an attribute you can pass a set of attributes and count each and return the list of counts.

Comment: @Volker yes, that works, ill post an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no special sauce in Go to do this. You're expected to write a loop over the slice - that's OK.

Your original code is absolutely fine, especially if you need to perform several different counts in the same loop. The `count2` function is fine too, it abstracts away a bit of the code (not much though), but it's only useful for a single counter - a single filter/test function.

You could keep generalizing it by, e.g. passing in a slice of `Metrics` structs where each one is:

```
type Metrics struct {
  Counter int
  Filter func(test) bool
}
```

It all depends on your exact needs.

If you're looking for the idiomatic Go way here: don't worry about premature abstraction too much. Write the clearest / most readable code to solve the immediate task at hand.

Comment: as you have so much karma perhaps you could give me a hint what is wrong with the question?

Comment: @Beginner: I'm sorry you're having a bad experience. I did not downvote your question or vote to close it, but I did my best at providing an answer :) So I don't think anything is wrong with it, though apparently some other folks do. Maybe they will chime in.

Comment: yes, fair enough. if its nothing obvious its ok, just didn't want to be doing anything offensive to the comunity.